# Why am I getting undefined after loading the page? But after refreshing the current page, I get normal data. How can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, signalr, use-effect

I'm gettin undefined in *hubConnection*, and my program doesn't work, but after refreshing everything works correctly. I've tried to make *hubConnection* as simple property, but it didn't help me. One more thing that I've already tried is to create *useRef* hook and check if *hubConnection* if not undefined, if it not, then block the *useEffect*, but my messages after this action has stopped work.

Code of the program:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { routes } from "../../../../Environment";
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'
import Font from "../../../data/fonts/Font";
import { GiftedChat, Bubble, Send, InputToolbar } from 'react-native-gifted-chat'
import { container } from 'tsyringe';
import ChatService from "../../../../api-service/chat-service/ChatService";
import { AuthContext } from "../../auth/AuthProvider";
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder } from "@microsoft/signalr";

const Chat = (props: any) => {
    const chatService = container.resolve(ChatService);
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [hubConnection, setHubConnection] = useState<HubConnection>();
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const getRandomInt = (max: number) => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        setMessages([
            {
                _id: 1,
                text: 'Hello dude',
                createdAt: new Date(),
                user: {
                    _id: 2,
                    name: 'React Native',
                    avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',
                },
            },
            {
                _id: 2,
                text: 'Hello Tom',
                createdAt: new Date(),
                user: {
                    _id: user?.id.toString()!,
                    name: 'React Native',
                    avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',
                },
            },
            {
                _id: 3,
                text: 'How are you?',
                createdAt: new Date(),
                user: {
                    _id: 2,
                    name: 'React Native',
                    avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',
                },
            },
        ])


        const hubConnectionFunc = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(routes.chatUrl)
            .build();
        hubConnectionFunc?.start().then(() => "Connection started!");
        hubConnectionFunc.on("RecieveMessage", message => {
            console.log(messages[0].text);
            setMessages(previousMessages => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, {
                _id: getRandomInt(10000),
                text: message,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                user: {
                    _id: user?.id.toString()!,
                    name: 'React Native',
                    avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',
                },
            }))
        })
        setHubConnection(hubConnectionFunc);
        console.log(hubConnection);
    }, [])

    const onSend = useCallback((messages = []) => {
        hubConnection?.invoke("SendMessage", messages[0].text)
            .catch((err: any) => console.log(err));
        setMessage("");
    }, [])


    const renderBubble = (props: any) => {
        return (
            <Bubble
                {...props}
                wrapperStyle={{
                    left: {
                        backgroundColor: "#F1F1F4",
                    },
                    right: {
                        backgroundColor: "#EB7A89"
                    }
                }}
                textStyle={{
                    left: {
                        color: "#000000"
                    },
                    right: {
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    }
                }}
            />
        );
    }
    const renderSend = (props: any) => {
        return (
            <Send {...props}>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Icon
                        name='paper-plane'
                        type='font-awesome'
                        color='white'
                    />
                </View>
            </Send>
        )
    }

    const renderInputToolbar = (props: any) => {
        return (
            <InputToolbar {...props} primaryStyle={{
                borderWidth: 2,
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                height: 44
            }}
            />
        )
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.chatWrapper}>
            <GiftedChat
                placeholder="Aa"
                renderTime={() => <View></View>}
                maxInputLength={500}
                messages={messages}
                onInputTextChanged={setMessage}
                text={message}
                onSend={onSend}
                scrollToBottom
                alwaysShowSend
                user={{
                    _id: user?.id.toString()!,
                    name: user?.name!,
                }}
                renderBubble={renderBubble}
                renderSend={renderSend}
                renderInputToolbar={renderInputToolbar}
            />
        </View >
    )
}
```

[NodeJS console after first loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtvFF.png)

[NodeJS console after refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxILo.png)

Comment: What exactly is undefined, `hubConnection`? Is there an error message stating `hubConnection` is undefined? Where and what is checking/verifying that `hubConnection` is undefined?

Comment: 1) yes, hubConnection is undefined, after using setHubConnection in useEffect() 2) There is no error, just undefined in hubConnection   3) I'm checking it in the useEffect() in the end, I output it into the console.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's what I originally thought but I wanted confirmation from you. React state updates are asynchronous, so when you console log state it'll be the state from the ***current*** render cycle, not the state you just enqueued for the ***next*** render cycle. If you want to log state updates then use a separate effect just for that state, i.e. something like `useEffect(() => console.log(hubConnection), [hubConnection]);` This effect callback will be triggered when the dependency is updated.

Comment: Yep, but it gonna kill me, your approach is working, I can see the data, but it works only on the useEffect, if I don't output data in some function(for example onClick event) I get an undefined again.

Comment: I get undefined here `const onSend = useCallback((messages = []) => {
        console.log(hubConnection);
        hubConnection?.invoke("SendMessage", messages[0].text)
            .catch((err: any) => console.log(err));
        setMessage("");
    }, [])`

Comment: Your other hooks should probably have dependencies  `hubConnection` for sure on the `useCallback` since it is undefined on the initial render and the memoized callback should re-enclose any updated `hubConnection` values so it is current.

Comment:  can you help me with that, How can I refresh data inside useCallback ()

Comment: `const onSend = useCallback((messages = []) => {....}, [hubConnection, /* include any other dependencies the linter complains about */])`. You may not even need to memoize the `onSend` callback, it's only sent to 1 component and only makes a call to the hub connection to send a message and clears the local message state. these are both asynchronous actions.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your data not Loading 1st time but when you refresh your screen again it loads your data to fix this issue you can use async-await or && logic

Comment: Can you clarify more correctly, what exactly I have to change? Please